# Priority spam tx?

Tags: tip-selection, spam

I was spamming my fullnode for educational purposes. Although I am helping other tx to get confirmed, I noticed that my own spam tx have a very low confirmation probability.

- Is it intentionally and a characteristic of the TipsManager that 0-value tx almost never get picked for approval?
- Or might it be coordinator-related?
- Why would you even bother to check a 0-value tx?

As a spammer I use the one found on [github](https://github.com/pRizz/iota.transactionSpammer.js/blob/4621bb57bd07a30df6ada8fd4d6019a11eb39f42/src/transactionSpammer.js).

Answer (score 1):

Tip selection for approval does not look at the amounts at all, so it should not matter whether you do value transactions or zero-value transactions.

however, I'd check that your node is synced (otherwise your spam is only approving outdated transactions and that makes it unlikely for anyone to approve your spam), and that the transactions you are spamming are reaching the rest of the world (otherwise nobody can see and confirm them).

And for the record: If nobody confirms your transactions, they don't help confirming other transactions either.

Comment: good to hear that tip approval does not discriminate. i have a healthy fully synced node with two solid neighbors and nelson on top. but looking at the low confirmation rate of my spam resuls, i can only conclude that IRI is somehow not functioning as intended. how could i further confirm my findings?

Comment: here is the [address](https://thetangle.org/address/DMGAZUVUCOQTMKFETJRCMEYIPPSOAKCQQKFMYXBNWZEMQYBUWIXRVUSMCCMZNZJPBEGMOKOMOEEQMRDXN) which contains my spam tx

Comment: but on the other hand is approval even necessary for data transactions??? how does the check look like for these data tx (since there is no need at least for a double spending check)

Comment: As you are approving two other transactions with your spam transaction, the double spend check has to verify that both "branches" don't try to spend the same iotas differently (which has already been done by your node too, but what if your node is the rogue one?). So every transaction needs to get confirmed eventually so that others can trust it and treat the "tree" below it as confirmed too.

Comment: perhaps you can also show the code you are using to select the tips for your spamming. Perhaps that code selects inconsistent tips? (If you just use "getTransactionsToApprove" and have a current IRI version, this is handled by your node already, but there are some people who think they do their own "tip selection"...)

Comment: i edited my question. you can find the link there. basically i call iota.api.sendTransfer without any tipselection on my end. i guess it is all done by full node itself.